# How do I describe my “eldest sister”, “second eldest sister” and “third eldest sister” in French?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

I have 3 older sisters (I am the youngest). if I was speaking to a French person and I had to differentiate between my 3 sisters without saying their names, how would I describe them?

I know there is "ma sœur aînée. ma deuxième sœur aînée. mon troisième aîné” - but I imagine there would be a specific word for each level of sibling?

Answer (score 1):

*Ma sœur ainée* might be considered ambiguous as there are more than one.

I would say: *L'ainée de mes sœurs, la deuxième, la troisième*.

There are also specific words: *l'ainée de mes sœurs, la cadette, la benjamine*.

They are however less used nowadays, especially *benjamine*.